# Having problem to find all solutions using the Chinese Remainder Theorem

Tags: number-theory, chinese-remainder-theorem

Find all solutions using the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

```
x = 2 (mod 4)
x = 3 (mod 5)
x = 9 (mod 13)
```

My step is here:

```
a = 2 (mod 4) , a = 0 (mod 5) , a = 0 (mod 13)
b = 0 (mod 4) , b = 3 (mod 5) , b = 0 (mod 13)
c = 0 (mod 4) , c = 0 (mod 5) , c = 9 (mod 13)
```

The general solution for x is given by `x = a + b + c + k*lcm(4,5,13) = a+b+c+260k`

since `a = 0 (mod 5) and a = 0 (mod 13)`, so `a = 65m` for some integer m
then `65m = 2 (mod 4)`

What should i do next?
I think the step i write `65m - 2 = 4` is wrong

Comment: Not sure I understand the method you are using...how does it save any time?  Just go stage by stage.  To solve the first two congruences, write $x=2+4A$ and solve $2+4A\equiv 3 \pmod 5\implies A\equiv 4 \pmod 5$ so we have $x=2+4(4+5B)=18+20B$.  Now solve $18+20B\equiv 9 \pmod {13}$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  $x\equiv-2\bmod4$ and $x\equiv-2\bmod5\implies x\equiv-2\bmod 20$.  Now solve that and $x\equiv9\bmod 13$

Comment: I added an answer showing how to use the *constant-case* CRT optimization mentioned by @J.W.T  This is the easiest approach in cases like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have ,

$$x\equiv2 \mod 4 \implies \color{#d05}{x=4a+2}\\ $$  
$$\begin{align}x&\equiv3 \mod 5 \\4a+2&\equiv3\mod5\\  4a&\equiv 1\mod5 \\ a &\equiv 4 \mod 5\implies\color{#2cd}{a = 5b+4}\end{align} $$  
 
$$\begin{align}x&\equiv9 \mod 13 \\ 4(5b+4)+2&\equiv 9\mod13 \\ 20b+18&\equiv9\mod13 \\ 20b&\equiv 4\mod 13 \implies  \color{#2c0}{b = 13c+8}\end{align}  $$

So , $x = 4a+2 = 20b+18=260c + 178$

Comment: To fill the two gaps: $\ a = 5b+4\, $ so $\,x = 4a+2 = 4(5b+4) = 20b+18.\ $ $\bmod 13\!:\ 9\equiv x\equiv 20b+18 \equiv -6b+18\iff 6b\equiv 9\iff b\equiv 9/6\equiv 3/2\equiv 16/2\equiv 8.\ $ This method of solving the congruences in pairs works generally, [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1181523/242) for a proof.

Comment: @BillDubuque I Left that for the O.P to fill in . On a different note , why was the answer downvoted ?

Comment: Maybe due to the gaps? The 2nd one, solving $\,  6b\equiv 9\pmod{13}\,$ is often a stumbling block in problems like these, so it helps to say how to solve it.

Comment: The edit still doesn't show how you deduced $\bmod 13\!:\ 20b\equiv 4\iff b\equiv 8\ \ $ Also *all* arrows need to be *bidirectional* to concude that the necessary conditions are also *sufficient* (else  root(s) might be extraneous)

Answer (score 1):

Following @lulu's suggestion,  but using Bezout coefficients,  we first get for $\begin{cases} x\cong2\pmod4\\x\cong3\pmod5\end{cases}$, that  $-1\cdot4+1\cdot 5=1$.

Now, by a well known result,  detailed in the section "Using the existence construction" of "Computation" in [this article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) ,  we get  $x=(-4)\cdot 3+(5)\cdot 2=-2+20k$.

Then, repeat for $20$ and $13$.  That is, take $\begin {cases} x\cong-2\pmod{20}\\x\cong 9\pmod{13}\end{cases}$.

So $2\cdot20+-3\cdot 13=1$.

And we get $x=40\cdot9+(-39)\cdot (-2)=438+260k$, or $x=178+260k$, as our solution.

Comment: `\equiv` not `\cong`.

Comment: You should explain the big leap from the Bzout equation to the CRT solution. One easy way is [described here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2060729/242) by **scaling and rearranging the Bezout gcd equation**

Comment: @BillDubuque see for instance  section $4.3$ of the following article https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem

Comment: I know how to do it, but you need to explain that to your readers, and it belongs in the answer, e.g.  "by using Bezout to compute inverses then using [this  well-known CRT formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#Existence_%28direct_construction%29) we obtain ...." That's a direct link to that Wiki section. Btw,  if you've never seen it, the Bezout scaling & rearranging way is easier so worth knowing.

Answer (score 1):

By [CCRT](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/190522/242)  $\,x\equiv -2\pmod{\!4,5}\!\iff\! x\equiv \color{#0a0}{-2\pmod{\!20}}$
$\,\bmod \color{#c00}{13^{\phantom{|^|}}}\!\!\!\!:\,\ 9\equiv x\equiv \color{#0a0}{-2\!+\!20}\color{#c00}k\equiv -2\!-\!6k\!\iff\! 6k\equiv -11\equiv-24\!\iff\! \color{#c00}{k\equiv -4}$
So we conclude $\ x = -2^{\phantom{|^i}}\!\!\!\!+\!20(\color{#c00}{-4\! +\! 13}n) = -82+260n,\, $ using only trivial mental arithmetic.

---

**Remark** $\ $ We solved $\bmod 13\!:\ 6x\equiv 6(-4)\ $ using $$\bmod n\!:\  ax\equiv ab\iff x\equiv b,\ \ {\rm when}\ \ \gcd(a,n)=1\!$$

since [by Bezout,](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2326680/242) $\,a\,$ is invertible so *cancellable* from LHS, i.e. scale LHS by $\,a^{-1}\,$ to cancel $\,a,\,$ using the [Congruence Product Rule.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242)

Such linear congruences are often *much* easier to solve using modular *fractions*, e.g. see my comment below, and see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3434593/242), and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2368266/242) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3379575/242) for circa $20$ motley worked examples via a handful of methods.

Comment: I think you meant $-82$ where you typed $-84$

Comment: There's more than one way to skin a cat:  $\mod 13:\;9\equiv-2-6k\iff 4\equiv2+6k\iff 2\equiv1+3k\iff 1\equiv 3k\iff k\equiv9$, so we'd conclude $x=-2+20(9+13n)=178+260n$

Comment: @J.W.T typo fixed, tx. Yes. many ways to evaluate $\!\bmod 13\!:\ \color{#c00}k\equiv \dfrac{2}6\equiv \dfrac{1}3\equiv \dfrac{-12}3\equiv -4,\ $ or $k\equiv \dfrac{2(-2)}{6(-2)}\equiv \dfrac{-4}1\ $ by [Gauss's algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/174687/242), or $\,\color{#c00}{\dfrac{2}{3}}\equiv \dfrac{15}3\equiv\color{#c00} 5\,\Rightarrow\,\dfrac{2}{6}\equiv \color{#c00}{\dfrac{2}{3}}\dfrac{1}2\equiv \dfrac{\color{#c00}5}2\equiv \dfrac{18}2\equiv 9\ \ $